# server-status in wordpress htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I want to enable server-status from mod_status

I have this on .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

httpd.conf is

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
    Allow from 111.11.1.1
</Location>
```

I'm using my external IP. I'm using this website to know my IP address. https://www.whatismyip.com/

But when I access example.com/server-status it's a 403 forbidden but then when I change the http conf to allow from all it can be accessed but I want it to only be accessible to my computer

Comment: Check the access log to see which ip is really making the requests.

Comment: It's my IP                                                                                          111.11.1.1- -                                                                           [04/Nov/2016:15:26:22 +0000] "GET /server-status HTTP/1.1" 404 68213 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36"

Comment: well, a 404 means you were not getting forbidden, just that you weren't landing in the context where location was defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directive [`Order`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#order) can be tricky, maybe that's the reason why it is deprecated.

Nevertheless, when you want to use it, just go by the examples in the documentation

> In the following example, all hosts in the example.org domain are allowed access; all other hosts are denied access.
>
> ```
>  Order Deny,Allow  
>  Deny from all  
>  Allow from example.org
> ```

Do you see the different order of `Deny,Allow`?

---

To use the current [`Require`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) directive, this should work

```
Require ip 111.11.1.1
```

Comment: Thanks this did work I changed the Order to Deny,Allow then allow from 111.11.1.1 ... I did not use the require IP